# Is it possible to show only the content that overflows of a tag?

Tags: css

I know that you can do `overflow: hidden` when an element overflows of a tag (`div`, `p`, etc) to hide the content that overflows.

Is it possible to make the opposite behaviour?

Only show the content that overflows. I searched about it but I could not find anything related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too sure i get what you wan to do *(I added a slide effect to snippet togive it some meanings :) )*, but relative and z-index could do:

```css
p {
  width:400px;
  padding:1em;
  margin:0;
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
  border:solid blue;
  background:lightblue;
  transition:0.5s;
}
div {
  width:200px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/300/nature/8) white;
  background-size:cover;
}
div:hover p {
  margin-left:200px;
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I love your slide effect :) +1 but I will wait a bit more to see if there are more approachs to get only the overflow. I thought about hide it with a div but I was looking for something more cleaner (the reason of my question :p)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just overflow the content.
To do that, you will need to create some tag such as div for that content.
Then, you overflow that div tag together with your content.

I don't see any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible with CSS. One idea:

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: #ccc;
  background: #bada55;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/aZbXpa)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more your code please? And why in your codepen do you have `&:after`?

Comment: On Codepen you can use CSS preprocessors like LESS or SASS (`&:after` is the same as `div:after` - you can click `View Compiled` to see actual CSS). I used pseudo element to cover the main div with white background (same as body) to hide whats behind it. If you remove this pseudo element you will see the actual div with content.

Comment: So if you have a background-image for example on the main div, you cannot use this approach, right?

Comment: Right, if you have `background-image` for example on body, applying the same `background-image` to pseudo element won't be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Add a layer on top of the div with the overflowing content using absolute positioning. Make the top layer solid with fixed dimensions. When the content grows it will stay in one place and it will seem as if only the overflowing content is appearing where you want it to.